# Inserting All of CheckBoxList Data into DB

Tags: asp.net

I have a form that users will fill out and when they submit, all data is pushed to a database.

My Problem is that I have a CheckBoxList and if a user selects multiple checkboxes it only inputs the first item into the database. How do I make it so that all the items are inputted into the same row and separated by commas.

Here is my current code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Start Code
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = conString + txtFirst.Text + "','" + txtLast.Text + 
        "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + lstBranch.Text + "','" + lstAccess.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Don't structure your data like this. This is badly de-normalised. You'll find it difficult to query this data (e.g. to filter it, or find specific items, or sort it, or count the items) later. Study entity-relationship design and database normalisation and understand how to structure your tables so that you don't have redundant data and you don't store multiple values in a single field. In this case you probably need a child table where there's one row for each checkbox item selected, with a foreign key column associating the entry back to the right row in the parent table.

Comment: Not to mention, this SQL statement is wide open to injection attacks. Rethink your approach to this problem.

Comment: @ADyson , I am aware that this is not a good way to do it but it is quick and is only for personal use. Will not be public at all. Is there a way to push all selected item in a single row. If not how would I build it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the items like this

```
string result = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < checkboxlist1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (checkboxlist1.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        result += checkboxlist1.Items[i].Text + ", ";
    }
}

// remove the final comma.
// add 'result' to your sql stmt.
```